# PyGame decreases image quality on image load

Tags: image, pygame

I am displaying a series of images as a presentation fullscreen on a monitor of which the native resolution is 1280x720. The images that need to be displayed are 1280x720px to make sure they do not need to be converted. The images are jpg high quality.

When I blit the image to the surface it shows the image in the correct size, filling the screen. That is as I expected it to show.

However, the image displayed seems to be compressed. The compression looks like a jpeg compression of about 80/100. That seems pretty much ok, but this leads to problemarea's which show up clearly on the display. The code below is what I have now. The PyGame documentation doesn't really show any quality setting so I'm hoping I do not have to move to another way to do it, although that would be fine...

```
pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
# move mouse pointer off of the screen
pygame.mouse.set_pos((1280, 720))   
pygame.display.update()

# Get the image from disk (with or without convert() shows same result)
picture = pygame.image.load(image).convert()

# smoothscale suggested on stack overflow, but shows no difference.
picture = pygame.transform.smoothscale(picture, (1280, 720))

# Get the screen surface to display an image on and blit
main_surface = pygame.display.get_surface()
main_surface.blit(picture, (0, 0))
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: As you said images already are 1280x720. What happends if you remove the scale line?
The problem is that you see the image in pygame with lower quality than the original image, doesn't it?

Comment: Like you can see in the comment above that line smoothscale was suggested but makes no difference with or without. Same goes for convert().

Comment: What `bpp` is the display created at?

Comment: bits per pixel? In that case I tried 16, 24 and 32. None of those seem to make a difference

Comment: I forgot to mention that I can scale down the image using smoothscale. The compression artifacts are scaled down as well. So compression happens before smoothscale.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell from the code what the actual image file type is. When I get unexplainable output in Pygame I would first try the following:

1) run the game from the command line not the shell (F5). The shell runs from Tkinter which has its own infinite loop and can cause unwanted consequences in your program.

2) run your program from the directory by double clicking.

2) try changing the image file type within Photoshop. I generally use .png or jpeg.Depending on which one you are using try the other.

3) In Photoshop reduce the file size manually using "save as web" and see if this helps.

4) Use another picture to check if it happens with all pictures or just this one.

The reason I suggest the above  are that I would use pretty similar code so would look for alternative solutions.I am sure the functions in Pygame are not to blame as they would be have been reported by now bu users on forums?

Comment: I am unsure where the problem lies, but I tried other images that have the exact same problem (4). What I was about to try is using the best or worst quality available (3) (perhaps images are too large with 200KB - 600KB?)

(1) and (2) I am unable to try because this isn't actually a game. I was advised to look at pygame which I was alreacdy using to solve the problem instread of finding another method to show an image fullscreen from the command line...

Comment: what happens if you remove the first update command? Could you link to the picture so I can download and try myself for you?

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten the code to simplify:

```
 #pygame code to render an image
 import pygame, os
 image = 'solution.jpg'  #located in same folder as this file:resized in Photoshop 
 pygame.init()  #I assume you did this?
 SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
 pygame.mouse.set_pos((1280, 720))
 picture = pygame.image.load(image)
 SCREEN.blit(picture,(0,0))
 pygame.display.update()enter code here
```

This worked fine:

1) I have only one pygame update instead of two;I do not use the get_surface() method; I created a variable for the surface called screen.

2) Perhaps try .png instead of .jpeg?

3) Another thought: was was the picture re-sized to 1280,720 and looking as you expected within Photoshop?

4) experiment with file types

```
JPG
PNG
GIF (non animated)
BMP
PCX
TGA (uncompressed)
TIF
LBM (and PBM)
PBM (and PGM, PPM)
XPM
```

All of the above are supported

I have tested the above code with photographs,res-sized them in Photoshop and with multiple images and no problems.If all else fails check you have the latest Pygame version and the correct one for OS?